# Ubuntu directly boots up without giving me a chance to reach Advanced Options

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I have a Lenovo laptop running Ubuntu 18.10 with kernel `4.19.0-041900-generic`.

Only Ubuntu is installed.

When I turn on the laptop it directly boots into Ubuntu. I want to go to Advanced Options to boot a different kernel.

Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and hold while booting. For UEFI boot press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and hold.

Comment: I have tried both, but in vain. Nothing works